# How can I improve AWS RDS MySQL instance performance for high concurrent connections?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-rds

We're testing the performance of different AWS RDS MySQL instances for a project, with a focus on handling a potentially large number of concurrent connections. We've conducted latency tests with 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, and 30 concurrent connections on t2.micro, t3.micro, t2.small, and t3.small instances.

Surprisingly, we found that the latency performance dropped off consistently at 20 or more concurrent connections across all instances, and the latency performance for each experiment was similar across all instances. We had expected that upgrading from t2 to t3 (with an extra CPU) and from micro to small instance types would improve performance, but this did not seem to be the case.

We're now wondering if there are other factors that affect concurrent performance beyond simply scaling up instance sizes. What could be causing this behavior, and how can we improve the performance for high concurrent connection loads? While this isn't currently an urgent issue, we're curious about how these instances work and would like to be prepared for any potential future problems.

edit:
Test setup -
Lambda functions are created with APIs. The lambda functions run MySQL queries.
Co-current API calls are made and data is collected on each test.
test cases (10 tests a piece, average execution time per API call) -

- 1 co-current API call  :  0.25 avg/call
- 2 co-current API call  :  0.24 avg/call
- 3 co-current API call  :  0.24 avg/call
- 5 co-current API call  :  0.28 avg/call
- 10 co-current API call :  0.36 avg/call
- 20 co-current API call :  1.16 avg/call
- 50 co-current API call :  2.16 avg/call

Comment: How are you conducting these tests? Also, how is this lambda related. In any case, I think you may get some use out of [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/). If they all drop off at 20 it sounds like there is a configuration on database or caller side maxed at 20 and context switching is happening, but it is tough to say.

Comment: Added some test details.
I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: AWS t2 and t3 types are NOT meant to be used for high concurrency applications. Review this url, please  -  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/    - if you WANT to pursue improving performance on the t2 and t3 types anyway - because you can, provide data after stop/start of t3 type and completion of you 50 con-current testing and some suggestions for performance improvement will be provided for you.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide speed improving suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> latency performance dropped off consistently at 20 or more concurrent connections across all instances,

That is a fact with MySQL.

MySQL gives equal opportunity to each connection.  And since, the connections are [presumably] clamoring for the same resources and data, they are stumbling over each other [especially in contrived benchmarks].

Be aware that off-the-shelf benchmark programs tend to look for exactly what you found -- where the product will break.  A benchmark that involves *your* application will point out [probably]  that you don't have a problem because you are not really going to pound on the database that hard.  A thousand users is [usually] no problem because they run at human speed, not benchmark speed.

For example, a users connect, then it is seconds before they press the Submit button.  If the app is well designed, there will be only 5-50ms of CPU work done before it is back to the user to read the results.  That says that a single CPU chan handle hundreds of users *sequentially*.

"Sequentially" is closer to reality than a benchmark that tries to achieve "concurrency".